# Memory warning creating new object of root view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, uinavigationcontroller

In my project, I am having an outlet for navigation controller. This works perfectly in general, but whenever my app receives memory warning, it creates a new object of root view controller class, that is assigned to the navigation controller through interface builder. After this event, two objects of root view controller resides in the memory and events gets fired twice. This is creating a mess in my case. Can you please suggest me a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

release the member variables, in viewDidUnload method which is called whenever the memory warning occurs. dealloc is not called so u need to release in viewDidUnload.

hope this helps.. happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Currently I'm working around this concept only. Will confirm once I get it working for me.

Comment: This solution seems to be working. Though, in my case I had to take different approach to fix my problem.

Comment: gud to knw that u found out a solution. Thanx for accepting. happy coding :)